# Move Angular 2 generated files to separate folder

Tags: angular

I'm trying to clean up my work space from the generated files (mainly .js and .map). Taking the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) I tried adding `"outDir": "build",` to the tsconfig.json and then modifying index.html to use `System.import('build/boot')`, but I just get a blank "Loading..." page and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` on the console.

Related question, in case it is possible to move the generated files to a separate folder, what would happen to component files that are moved or renamed? Seems like the build folder will leave the old ones intact. Any way around it? (keep them in sync)

Comment: Try this angular2-seed project. http://mgechev.github.io/angular2-seed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can update `tsconfig.json` to generate javascript (and sourcemaps) in a different folder. However, you will also have to move static assets (HTML, CSS) into this folder too. I wrote a blog post about how to achieve this with Gulp:

[Creating an Angular 2 build with Gulp, TSLint and DefinitelyTyped](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/24/creating-an-angular-2-build.html)